# How to Close mobile keyboard when pressed enter JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input that doesn't have any buttons or forms. I want to hide the mobile keyboard after pressing enter on mobile phone (arrow one).

I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("input").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

but I don't know what to do after the `if` statement.

Comment: I have edited your post: added indentation to the code plus a few minor grammatical changes. Hopefully, this will make it a bit clearer to those who view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery blur method, I am pretty sure that would work.

https://api.jquery.com/blur/

```
$("input").blur();
```